# Allocating memory from a file, then using fread and fwrite C

Tags: c

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my code to work, which is to open a file, count the number of characters in it, and then allocating that using `malloc()`. And then I am supposed to read the characters in from one file (mine contained "Hello World!") using `fread()`, and write them to a blank `.txt` file using `fwrite`.

My code so far is printing corrupted characters. I couldn't find any questions that were specific enough to my problem. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it. I think it is specific to my `fread` and `fwrite` calls, but nothing I've tried works.

The code in question (not commented yet, sorry!):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//initialized using ./a.out in.txt out.txt

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int count, end;
    char *memory;
    char c[64]; 

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if((fp) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: cannot open file.\n");
    }

    else
    {
        while((fgetc(fp))!= EOF)
        {
            count++;    
        }

        memory = (char*)malloc(count);

        c[64] = fread(memory, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);

        fp = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        fwrite(c, sizeof(char), sizeof(c), fp); 

        fclose(fp);     
        free(memory);
    }       
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You forgot to initialise `count`.

Comment: Once you read the file once, you have to rewind it before you can reread it. (You forgot to initialize `count` to zero before you start.)  You didn't check that the memory allocation was successful. You can't write to `c[64]` reliably since `c[63]` is the last element of the array.   You only attempt to read one byte, not `count` bytes. The value returned by `fread` is the number of bytes read. That should be the number you write, not the size of the array.  You read the data into `memory` but you write the garbage from uninitialized array `c`.  That's enough to give you problems.

Comment: Also, minor points: `sizeof(char)` is redundant (just use `1`), and [casting the result of `malloc` is unnecessary and potentially dangerous in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler To be more correct the value returned by `fread` is the number of **items** read.

Comment: Be aware that the size of the file may have changed the second time you read it.

Comment: @skyking: Yes.  There are disadvantages to comments — like they have limited space and you can't edit them indefinitely.

Comment: After your `while` loop your `fp` is already at `EOF`! And I guess you don't want to read only 1 byte, but `count` with that `fread`. Same goes for `fwrite`. Look up `fseek` on how to set the file pointer to the beginning of the file again after your while loop.

Comment: Yeah.. there ought to be close reason for 'so many bugs/problems that it's not easily possible to pick out one to give a fix to'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

code have logical mistakes, as follow

1. Initialise variables `int count= 0 , char c[64]= {0};`
2. Type cast not required `memory = malloc(count);`
3. First you have counted number of char in file so Before reading again file rewind it by `fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);`
4. `c[64] = fread(memory, sizeof(char), 1, fp);`  In this if you are reading single  `char`, you should read complete file , To read complete file do `fread(memory, 1, count, fp);` and c[64] is out of bound  and `fread` return the number of char successfully read .
5. `fwrite(c, sizeof(char), sizeof(c), fp);` In this you are writing complete char array to file but you have read only single variable in array which number of char read . So you are writing uninitialised char array to file. so you are getting corrupted character in file.
6. To write  in file do `fwrite(memory, 1, count, fp);`

To solve problem ,avoid above error and read complete file in char array and then write.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` equals 1 by definition, therefore it can be replaced safely by `1`.

Comment: Since the variable `end` is unused, it should be deleted, not initialized.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I realized most were simple mistakes, but I finally understand how to use fread and fwrite. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, there are a number of problems here, I'll start with the least bad:

```
memory = (char*)malloc(count);
```

Casting the return of `malloc()` is unnecessary and can potentially mask errors, for more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

```
int count;
```

You never initialise `count` to anything. This is undefined behaviour and there is no guarantee it'll start at 0. It can start at random garbage left in memory. Same for `end`

```
    c[64] = fread(memory, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
```

2 Problems here. `c[64]` is out of bounds for the array `c` since indexes start at 0, so the last element in the array is `c[63]`. `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1, so use 1 instead. Further, `fread()` returns the amount of characters read, so not sure what you are trying to do with that value even.

```
fwrite(c, sizeof(char), sizeof(c), fp);
```

You're writing a complete uninitialised array to the file (=garbage)